# Не выводится произвольный тип записей wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-query

Есть несколько произвольных типов записей, согласно [иерархии](https://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png) шаблонов, необходимо использовать `archive.php` для вывода архивов этих записей.
Так вот проблема, не понятная мне, такова:
2 из 3х необходимых мне типов записей выводятся, а вот третий отказывается это делать. В место шаблона `archive.php` подключается шаблон `index.php`  и при этом записи не выводятся. Просто показывает пустую страницу.
Вот скрины происходящего:
[image: Пункт меню "Портфолио"]
[image: Пункт меню "Команда"]
Данный тест был проведен путем не хитрого добавления заголовка с именем шаблона в его разметку
Пункты меню собираются из произвольных ссылок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот код регистрации записей из `function.php`:

```
/**
* Тип записей "Портфолио"
**/
add_action('init', 'portfolio_post');
function portfolio_post(){
    register_post_type('portfolio', array(
        'description'         => 'Добавляет новые записи в Портфолио',
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical'=> false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail','excerpt'),
        'menu_position' => 4,
        'menu_icon' => admin_url() . 'images/portfolio.png',
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Портфолио',
            'all_items' => 'Все записи',
            'add_new' => 'Новая запись',
            'add_new_item' => 'Добавить новую запись'
        )
    ));
}  

/**
* Тип записей "команда"
**/
add_action('init', 'team');
function team(){
    register_post_type('team', array(
        'description'         => 'Добавляет новые записи к блоку "Команда"',
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical'=> false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail','excerpt'),
        'menu_position' => 4,
        'menu_icon' => admin_url() . 'images/portfolio.png',
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Команда',
            'all_items' => 'Вся команда',
            'add_new' => 'Добавить сотрудника',
            'add_new_item' => 'Добавить нового сотрудника'
        )
    ));
}
```

Причем в одном из шаблонов при обращении к `WP_Query` записи этого типа выводятся. Вот кусок кода из шаблона:

```
<!--team block-->
    <?php $team = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'team','posts_per_page' => 3, 'orderby' => 'rand')) ?>
        <section class="teams-block">
            <h2 class="teams-block_header">
                    <span class="teams-block_header_text">
                        Наша команда
                    </span>
                    <a class="teams-block_header_link-all" href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'team' ); ?>">
                        / Вся команда
                    </a>
                </h2>
            <div class="teams-block_content">
    <?php if ( $team->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $team->have_posts() ) : $team->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="teams-block_worker">
                    <a class="worker_foto" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                    <h3 class="worker_name"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <h4 class="worker_specialty"><?php my_list_tags(); ?></h4>
                    <div class="worker_info">
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <p>блок наша команда</p>
    <?php endif; ?> 
            </div>
        </section>
    <!--end team block-->
```

Выводится то они выводятся, но ссылки:

```
<a class="teams-block_header_link-all" href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'team' ); ?>">
```

и

```
<a class="worker_foto" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
```

Отправляют все на тот же пресловутый `index.php` без вывода информации.
Надеюсь я достаточно описал проблему и привел все необходимые данные для помощи в решении этой проблемки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ребят, кто столкнулся с подобной проблемой, просто не забывайте после регистрации произвольного типа записи отправляться в админку => настройки => постоянные ссылки и нажать кнопочку "сохранить изменения"